# How to set server name in PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit

I can't get a functional test working, so I ran a `var_dump` on the `$crawler` object to see what was going on.

I noticed the `$uri` of the crawler is set to `http://localhost/items` - I believe this is the issue. I have set the path to be /items so that is okay, but my web app is not installed at localhost (it is at `http://localhost/myapp/` - I also have an alias `http://myapp.local/`).

How do I configure PHPUnit (I am using Symfony2 if that makes a difference) so it points to either `http://localhost/myapp/items` or `http://myapp.local/items` for this functional test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is ever curious how I fixed this, in your `$client` you can set it like this:

```
$client = static::createClient(array(), array(
    'HTTP_HOST'     => 'myapp.local',
    ....
```

Comment: what is $client for you?